# file creation in linux

Tags: linux, glassfish

I have created an application in which the android mobile takes picture and uploads it to a server. The server accepts the image, stores in local directory and updates the path to the database. Everything works fine on my localhost (Windows) but when i deploy the war file it is not creating the file. The problem is my localhost is on windows but the main server(ISP) is on Linux. Both my localhost and main server (ISP) are using glassfish. On the main server (ISP) I am logging through admin and then deploying the war file.

Comment: You should check the permissions of your download / file directory. Windows allowing a lot more than linux.

Comment: i am understanging that the problem is of permission. Should i modify the permission of the directory where the the war file is stored ?

Comment: Best way is to set permissions to your web server process which includes new/edit/delete for items inside it. Another way is to set the permissions of the directory. You can use `chmod` for it.

Comment: How and where should i set glassfish server processes for the item inside it.

Comment: I don't know how it works with glassfish. You should read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem.

Where do you store your file in the server. In windows you might be giving the path as

```
D://images/dir1/......
```

In linux this path is not valid. It should look something like

```
/home/tomcat/images/repo/...........
```

Please post the code where you mention the location of the directory in which you store the images.

Comment: i am using System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator for creating directory